# ActiveRecord - Multiple conditions from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading a 3.2 Rails App (to Rails 4.1) and I am removing the [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) Gem, due to its lack of maintenance.

Here is an example:

```
incomplete = current_user.roles.where { (name == role.to_s) & (users_roles.status != 'completed') }.any?
```

Thus I have multiple conditions from multiple tables with one being a negative.  I would like your approach for this

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it...

```
incomplete = current_user.roles.where(name: role.to_s).where.not(user_roles: { status: 'complete'}).any?
```

Comment: Awesome Sean, that part putting the status in a hash was the thing I did not know